# javascript remove multiple objects from canvas with unique attribute

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

i'm using fabric js and trying to remove group of items when try to remove the parent item of group. following is my code.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', ".deleteBtn", function () {
    if (canvas.getActiveObject()) {
        var product_id = canvas.getActiveObject().get('product_id');
     }
        var canvasObj = canvas.getObjects();

    for(var i = 0; i < canvasObj.length; i++){

        var objRef = canvasObj[i];

        var accessoryId = objRef.get('accessory_product_id');

        var product_type = objRef.get('product_type');

        if(accessoryId == product_id && product_type == "accessory"){
            canvas.remove(objRef);
        }

    }
});
```

code is actually working, but not removing all items with same `accessoryId` and `product_type` parent item which is the active object trying to remove and two other items are removing properly. only two items left on canvas. there are all 5 items in group. those are images. i'm unable to find the issue please help. thanks!

HTML code

```
<div id="content-tab-3" class="visualiser-product-category content-tab active">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <img src="http://localhost/green_live/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Winter_Spice.png" class="visualizer-product-img" alt="Placeholder" data-quantity="1" data-product_type="parent" data-product_id="343">
              <img src="http://localhost/green_live/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Winter-Spice-Desk-Floral.jpg" class="hide accessory-343">
              <img src="http://localhost/green_live/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Winter-Spice-Garland.jpg" class="hide accessory-343">
              <img src="http://localhost/green_live/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Winter-Spice-Tabletop.jpg" class="hide accessory-343">
              <img src="http://localhost/green_live/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Winter-Spice-Wreath.jpg" class="hide accessory-343">
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please include the html markup

Comment: added. its not that important the html markup for the matter but as you asked. what i want to happen here is when use click on delete button in `data-product_type="parent"` all other images need removed from canvas. thanks

Comment: I was referring to the canvas, not random html from your page !

Comment: I'm using `fabric.js` library here. only canvas html markup im using here is 
 <div class="main" id="canvas-bgimg">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

Hello i noticed on your code that you **try to get the active's object id**, but no matter if there is active object or not you **proceed to the loop, to delete the objects**!!
Maybe, that causes the problem.

I'm going to show an example with **forEach() function**, but proceed to delete **objects ONLY if there is active object**:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', ".deleteBtn", function () {

    //only if there is active object, do i delete objects
    if (canvas.getActiveObject()) {
        //get productId of active object
        var product_id = canvas.getActiveObject().product_id;

        //loop on the canvas objects
        canvas.getObjects().forEach(function (object) {

               if(object.accessoryId == product_id && object.product_type ==  "accessory"){
                canvas.remove(object);
              }
        });//end forEach
    }//end if
});//end 'click'
```

Hope helps, good luck.